# Get value of selected RadioButtonList in aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx application with a RadioButton list like below:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblIsDiesel" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Diesel" class="carFuel" Value="true" Selected="True" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Petrol" class="carFuel" Value="false" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

In jQuery I am able to get the Buttons using the below:

```
var buttons = $('span.carFuel input:radio');
```

However, I am missing how to get the value of which RadioButton is selected.

What I am trying to do in pseudo code would be:

```
if (buttonSelected == Diesel) {
    alert("Diesel") 
} 
else {
    alert("Petrol") 
}
```

And secondly, fire an alert on toggling between the buttons.

```
if (valueChanged) {
    alert("You changed fuel type");
}
```

For the first question, I was trying to add :checked to the selector and then use .val() but that is giving me an undefined value. I believe the buttons selector I have above is working OK as if I add a debugger line, I can see 2 objects and the correct client side ids for the radio buttons.

And for the second part, I believe I will need to use the jQuery change event - just not sure on the correct selector.

Comment: Are you sure this jQuery works for you? I believe radio button list renders into table, not spans. Can you please post the resulting markup?

Comment: Yeah the mark up is generated with a span and if I execute the jQUery in the console I get both the Radio Buttons

Answer (score 0):

The key thing you seem to be missing is the [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx).

> When a Web server control is rendered as an HTML element, the id attribute of the HTML element is set to the value of the ClientID property.

With that, what you then do is look for the input control that is checked:

```
var selectedRB = $('#<%= rblIsDiesel.ClientID %> input:checked');
```

Then to get the value, just call `val()`.

```
var selectedValue = selectedRB.val();
```

But remember, this gets the *value* of the radiobutton, not the text. So with how you have it setup, you would see true or false as the value. And to be honest, I'm not totally sure I understand why the values would be true and false in your implementation - but that is beside the point.

To capture when the selected radiobutton changes, there is a handy `change` function that you can use:

```
$('#<%= rblIsDiesel.ClientID %> input').change(function() {
    alert("You changed fuel type");
});
```